# Nested routing in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I work on an app which I intend to have following structure:

```
-MAIN -  main “container” (main routes)    
--NCF (lazy loaded, routes for it’s subapps)    
---ACNP (lazy loaded)    
----Component1    
----Component2    
---SubApp2 (lazy loaded)    
---SubApp3 (lazy loaded)    
--App2 (lazy loaded)    
--App3 (lazy loaded)    
--…
```

It’s starting framework for app which will have 3 levels – MAIN, apps and subapps. Every app and subapp is to be developed independently. In future there may be more lazy-loaded levels.
I want routing to be maintained independently on each level, which means MAIN will handle routes (for lazy loading mainly) for NCF and App2 and App3; NCF will handle routes (again mostly lazy loaded) for ACNP, SubApp2 and SubApp3; ACNP will handle routes for its components.
Here’s how it looks right now:

MAIN-routes.ts:

```
import {Routes} from "@angular/router"

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'ncf',
    loadChildren: './ncf/ncf.module#NewCustomerFolderModule
  }
]
```

MAIN.html

```
<h1>FE2</h1>
<MAIN-nav></MAIN-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

MAIN-nav

```
<a [routerLink]="['/ncf']">New Customer Folder</a>
```

And it works fine, inside MAIN-nav I have links which lazy load NCFModule.

NCFModule.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(ncfRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [NewCustomerFolderComponent]
})
```

ncfRoutes.ts

```
import {Routes} from "@angular/router"
import { NCFComponent } from "./ncf.component"

export const ncfRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './acnp/acnp.module#AddCustomerNaturalPersonModule
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: NCFComponent
  }
]
```

ncf.html

```
<hr>
<a [routerLink]="['acnp']">Load ACNP</a>
<p>test</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

acnp.routes (right now I just want to load one component on default)::

```
export const acnpRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ACNPStepOneComponent
  }
]
```

Here’s where my problem begin: When I click on Load ACNP it is loaded, but it renders below first router-outlet (on MAIN level), but I want it to render below second router-outlet, defined in nfc.html.

I tried to do it using named router outlets:

ncf.html

```
<hr>
<a [routerLink]="['acnp', {outlets: {NCFRouterOutlet: ['acnp']}}]">Load ACNP</a>
<p>test</p>
<router-outlet name="NCFRouterOutlet"></router-outlet>

acnp.routes 
export const acnpRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ACNPStepOneComponent,
    outlet: 'NCFRouterOutlet'
  }
]
```

But hen when I click on Load ACNP I get error:

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find the outlet NCFRouterOutlet to load 'ACNPStepOneComponent'
```

How can I make components render below closest router-outlet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to update your `ncfRoutes.ts` so that `acnp` is a child route not on the same level,

```
export const ncfRoutes: Routes = [      
  {
    path: '',
    component: NCFComponent,
    children: [
           {
             path: 'acnp',
             loadChildren: './acnp/acnp.module#AddCustomerNaturalPersonModule
            }
     ]
  }
]
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/98ODt1MA6BmcoXkY4svv?p=preview), it has a solution for similar problem with three level of routes.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

In **Angular 8** you can create separate RoutingModules with components having their own Module.

[image]

In app-routing.module.ts file use **loadChildren** to load module of the child component

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
    { path: 'attendance', component: AttendanceComponent },
    { path: 'leaves', loadChildren: () => import(`./leaves/leaves.module`).then(m => m.LeavesModule) },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: Page404Component },
];
```

check full tutorial [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-nested-routing-with-multiple-routeroutlet-using-loadchildren-having-own-router-modules-example-application/)