# How to create Multiple router in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I Want to create more than 5 pages with link like
"Page 1/page 2/page 3/page 4" from root to page 1 and page 2 i know how connect using router. But afterwards how to continue the same anyone know's help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have nested routing in Angular. Apart from the routing you have already implemented, you can have routing inside each page. For example, you can have links to pages 1 and 2 from the root page which link to pages 3, 4 & 5 by specifying the children attribute in your routes.

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'page1', component: Page1Component,
        children: [
            { path: 'page3', component: Page3Component },
        ]
    },
    { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component,
      children: [
            { path: 'page4', component: Page4Component },
            { path: 'page5', component: Page5Component }
        ]
 }
];
```

Comment: If i do like this, its displaying  both parent page and child page, but i want to display only particular page

Comment: You need to call the proper routes using `<a routerLink="...">`. Take a look at this for correct implementation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390302/nested-routing-in-angular-2-4